# How to avoid SQL injection when a query is coming as a parameter of a method in Java?

Tags: java, sql-injection

```
public static RepositoryItem[] executeQuery(Repository repository, String query,Object[] params)
{
    RepositoryItem[] data = null;

    try {
        RepositoryView repositoryView = repository.getView(viewName);
        RqlStatement statement = RqlStatement.parseRqlStatement(query);
    }
}
```

The query is a parameterized query.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. Do you want to prevent any SQL contained in `params` from being executed or are you worried about the contents of `query`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which database your are using, you could define the SQL connection or DBConnectionPool using credentials of a user which has readonly access.
Any statement which is unauthorized will be rejected by the DBMS.